# How Do I change font-size in vuetify component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use v-text-field, and v-select, with vue-loader.
I tried to change font-size, but I could not.
How Do I change font-size?

My code likes this.

```
<template lang="pug">
p label-1
v-text-field(...)

p label-1
v-text-field(...)
</template>

<stylelang="sass">
.input-group .input-group__input
  font-size: 12px !important
</style>

<stylelang="sass"scoped>
.p
  font-size: 12px
</style>
```

[developer tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nekdE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the font-family on body. If you are importing the Vuetify stylus entry, main.styl overwrite the $font-family variable.

Comment: He asked about the font size, not font family

Answer (score 28):

To change the font size for a single component, such as a `text field`, application-wide:

```
<style>
  .v-text-field input {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
</style>
```

To change the font size within another component, use a scoped style:

```
<style scoped>
  .v-text-field input {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
</style>
```

For a more generic approach, you can also target multiple component types using `.v-input`

```
.v-input {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

or

```
.v-input input {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Finally, you can also target the labels as well.

```
.v-input .v-label {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: this styles did not help me on vuetify 2x, the best way to modify the font size on a <v-text-field> is using slots to override default label and use custom styles, please see docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots

Answer (score 13):

You could create a folder called sass, scss or styles in your src directory with a file named variables.scss or variables.sass. And add scss variable $input-font-size: 12px to the variables file. The vuetify-loader will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI's compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults.

```html
$font-size-root: 14px;
$input-font-size: 14px;
```

[Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#sass-variables) you could find details.

[Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#example-variable-file) you could find an example of the variables file.

Comment: Explanation to the query is clear :) also important is if you create the file for first time, re-serve the application.

Answer (score 9):

Using VueJS [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) worked for me:

```
<style lang="css" scoped>

.v-text-field >>> input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.v-text-field >>> label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.v-text-field >>> button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can create a div class and point this out.

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
  .element
    color white    
    padding 0
    margin 0
    font-size 150%
</style>

.element
      | 一共 : {{ sum("quantity") }} ，....
```

Answer (score 2):

I'am not sure what to use with `sass`, but for `scss` in vuetify you have to use the `::v-deep` selector instead of `>>>`:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

.v-text-field ::v-deep input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.v-text-field ::v-deep label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.v-text-field ::v-deep button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an asterisk selector `*` to match all descendants of an element or a component and then apply the font size like following:

```
.font-class-name * {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Then

```
<v-text-field class="font-class-name"></v-text-field>
```

Hope this works.