# how to change font-size of "v-text-field" in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, font-size

I am working in a "Nuxt" app and using "Vuetify" as my framework. this is the code of one of my components:

```html
<template>

<v-text-field
  color="var(--color4)"
  class="px-15"
>

  <template v-slot:label>

      <span class="labelClass">
          please enter your name
      </span>

  </template>

</v-text-field>

</template>

<style scoped>
.labelClass {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
</style>
```

I wanted to increase the font-size of label in input. according to [Vuetify ducomentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) we must use "slots" for doing that. so I added a new template and "slot" to that. Then I used **labelClass** for the **span** inside that to control the font-size. the font-size changed but the problem here is that if I increase  font-size (for example to 1.8rem), some parts of the text of that disappears:

[image]

And it becomes worse, if the font-size increases. I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967557/how-do-i-change-font-size-in-vuetify-component), but it did not help me. I also tried to set "height" prop for **v-text-field** and some classes like **v-text-field__slot** but they did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that after render the `input` get this `css` style:

```
.v-input input {
    max-height: 32px;
}
```

To solve this, you simply need to overwrite this. If you don´t want to override this for every `input`, just add another class to your `v-text-field`:

```
<v-text-field
  color="var(--color4)"
  class="px-15 my-class"
>
```

... and then use it like this:

```
.v-input.my-class input {
    max-height: 32px;
}
```

---

Edit: Looks like you also need to override the following style:

```
.v-input .v-label {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

This is the style of the label, you need to increase `height` and `line-height`. Another override needs to be done at:

```
.v-text-field input {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 8px 0 8px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `line-height` needs to be increased.

As your `html` in your `slot` is only displayed in the `slot`, `line-height` and `max-width` from parents affect the visible space.

Comment: Did you test it yourself? it does not work for me.

Comment: @hamid-davodi I tested it on the page of the documentation. Please inspect the structure in your browser after render.

Comment: I mean that again after increasing font-size the text disappears in my app and the "max-height" does not solve my problem.

Comment: it does not work for me, if you tested it please put the whole component code in your answer to check it.

Comment: @hamid-davodi Maybe because you provide the `css` in your component as scoped. As the `label` and `input` will be created during render and `<style scoped>` only affects already existing elements, you need to provide the styles global. If that still don´t solve your problem, please add the rendered `html` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use class="text-h3" inside

```
<v-text-field
 v-model="item"
 label="label"
 class="text-h3"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't solve the problem originally asked.