# How to change the font-size of Vuetify inputs locally?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

Given the following Vuetify Textfield component

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNkc1OwzAQhF8l2nNtSwUJKQpVuXPmUveQNltq8J9sJ4CqvDvrREUhObS+WF7vzjdj7y7w4j3vWoQSqoTG6zrhRtqCVtWxhN+JnRTqZiwVha4PqJ8lvOa9eHcYizMGlHBtMK5Bzbpat0htb3lftm0qMRUnYCX+6LACrexn5B/RWfJ1yTMSjjFKKIvdqCDhnJKPpRDHxlInQVUXuMUkrDeCEiV1+tk+8DVfi0bFdC0xShD5IJaV9tL2BFTGu5CYqf2MOl4M5KGSa6SUzzcsbKlNhNYmZZA1zgxeHp9GM5M6x2jYIbiviIFUJKwmnOz4DtatuIRYSAvidRhYQNvQ14R7I83G/sWa3S2iZXyfX7xfwThHbz+Yhv0vNrDaFA==)

```
<v-text-field label="Label goes here" model-value="Value goes here"></v-text-field>
```

The general font-size is way too big for my application. I want to lower down the label and text size. For the text I tried

```
.v-text-field input {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

but I can't figure out the CSS selector for the label, this didn't work for me

```
.v-text-field label {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

The second problem is that this solution **only** works **without** the `scoped` attribute and I don't know why.

Do you have any ideas? This question might be a duplicate of [How Do I change font-size in vuetify component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967557/how-do-i-change-font-size-in-vuetify-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question first, scoped CSS only applies to elements in the component. The `:deep()` selector allows you to target nested elements, i.e:

```css
:deep(.v-text-field input) {
    ...
}
```

The [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) explains it quite neatly.

---

The label itself can be targeted like this:

```css
:deep(.v-label.v-field-label.v-field-label--floating){
  --v-field-label-scale: 0.75em; /* .75em is the default value */
}
```

---

The elements inside `v-input` use relative sizes, so you can also set them together. Only the non-floating label (when no input is set) has to be unset for this to work:

```css
:deep(.v-field){
  font-size: 12px;
}
:deep(.v-label.v-field-label){
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

not sure about the animation though...

Here is a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlU01z0zAQ/StCHNwOsd0204tJO+XCcOfAoe7BsTdUoK+RNiYl4//OSrYTO4WhM7kk+73vvZUf9/yTtVm7BV7wFYKyskK4LzVjqzatrI1mdFQl9OCR34j24DB2tKjQS9GAY0rou5LflpypakfW8opMj2DJviaTJpoGJHkbo/Gr+A0UlNU6hj5TiIVYUfLJHnaAyN4TONDN/X4/tned3a3yGYfYko+QJqEZ/NGYkmOFxxcJBOUwv2CjxT6wxO6SjgDXsvKeqlSVLmdQSQiEHaYbAbKZkFX++4TnM0hpghiVE5VGipgtSqGhKXn+z2lntp8HZi7e/D9ofXgnwelf0Owq5PraCYvMA25DWihrHLI9c7BhHds4o1hCTzIpdW20x6Pud6Hk4vrmcswQgSGYfAno2TfjZPMuoYJV3q8J++Mtma+NhSZgKxoAe5G1qdB2i5eLYyAqdLnv6YS9qY+nF/oZnMCPIdGFn0NHVG/s7L3/9xO4AImw8AXv+ZNwNvvhjaYvMfaXQ8KXvGDDxJKTLsGnayFaX+R53Whqo3uK1mUaMNdW5Q9UlrutRqEgbYx6WGbL7CpdA1bZLR3Q4zSbgVfp2plfHhzNKvlisg3F5uUNG4dKWnSTLfsNQyho4sOKV6Nz2teCSx19yODAvZXYSdtfyJ1UvCI4nKEj9emB//Qnwtc+iv44Yj2LeRwWJj2Fhd2CT+ESgNjHn/4A7RDNIQ==) where you can see how it changes together